# Why does the formula for the volume of a rhombic triacontahedron contain $\sqrt{5}$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

The volume of a [rhombic triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron#Dimensions) is calculated by utilising the formula: 
$$V = 4a^3 \sqrt{ 5+2 \sqrt{5}}$$
where $a$ is the length of an edge.

The rhombic triacontahedron is a polyhedron with a thirty faces; it is a Catalan solid and zonohedron.

> Could someone kindly provide me with some insight as to why the formula contains $\sqrt{5}$, featured twice?

Comment: I fixed the formatting and made some minor edits to add context; please double-check that I didn't mess anything up. At some point (soon?), you're really going to need to [learn MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409).

Comment: The rhombic triacontahedron features [regular pentagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Regular_pentagons) (not as faces, but as figures that appear when joining certain groups of five vertices). While pentagons don't always introduce $\sqrt{5}$ (or, for that matter, the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)) into every formula they touch, it's rarely a surprise when they do.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article: "The ratio of the long diagonal to the short diagonal of each face is exactly equal to the **golden ratio**."

Comment: I'd say it is due to icosahedral symmetry.